# Numeric array: add value of previous element to current element

Tags: php, arrays

For each element in the array, I need to add value of previous element to it's current element. Example:

```
Array
(
     [0] => 460
     [1] => 25
     [2] => 25
     [3] => 25
     [4] => 25
     [5] => 25
     [6] => 25
)
```

How can I get like following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 460
    [1] => 485
    [2] => 510
    [3] => 535
    [4] => 560
    [5] => 585
    [6] => 610
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: A simple `foreach()` loop should allow you to do this very easily: `$r = 0; foreach($myArray as $key => $value) { $r += $value; $myArray[$key] = $r; }`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quicker solution compared to the rest:

```
foreach ($a as $i => $val) {
    // make sure the current item is not the first one.
    // because the first one is the base number
    if ($i > 0) {
       // Update current $i (INDEX) by
       // adding the previous value ($a[$i -1]) with the current value ($val)
        $a[$i] = $a[$i - 1] + $val;
    }
}
```

<sup>*As `0` is the first value, we can't increment before it :) hence the `if` statement*</sup>

And here is a demo: [**`Example`**](https://eval.in/171627)

---

It doesn't matter about what looping method you use, it's how you apply it. Look, here's the exact same thing done in a `for` loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
    if($i > 0) {
        $a[$i] = $a[$i - 1] + $a[$i];
    }
}
```

It all comes down to the preference of the coder using it.

---

Both of those loops return the correct data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 460
    [1] => 485
    [2] => 510
    [3] => 535
    [4] => 560
    [5] => 585
    [6] => 610
)
```

Comment: How you define quicker? You mean shorter in length? Or faster execution time?

Comment: +1 for not declaring any additional variables. BTW. Never say quicker. The execution time should be checked and counted, because of the n compares.

Comment: @wumm instead of instantiating more variables, just referencing the array.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
$source = array(460, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25);
$result = array();

$last = 0;
foreach($source as $s){
    $last = $result[] = $s+$last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$previous = 0;
foreach ($a as $key => &$value)
    $previous = $value = $previous + $value;
```

or

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($a as $key => &$value)
{
    $sum += $value;
    $value = $sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of the previous index (do check if `index` > 0), and add it to the current value.

```
$values = array(
     460,
     25,
     25,
     25,
     25,
     25,
     25
);

foreach($values as $key => &$value){

   if($key > 0){
    $prev_value = $values[$key-1];
    $value += $prev_value;
   }
}

echo print_r($values);
```

Comment: To get the value of the previous value

Comment: What about key = 0-1?

Answer (score 0):

> $array1 = (460, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25);
>
> function calculateAdjecentSum($array1)
>
> {
>
> $array2 = array();
>
> $pointer = 0;
>
> foreach ($array1 as $number) {
>
> ```
>    $sum      = $pointer + $number;
>
>    $array2[] = $sum; 
>
>    $pointer  = $sum;
> ```
>
> }
>
> return $array2;
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to use for loop:

```
<?php

$array = array
(
     0 => 460,
     1 => 25,
     2 => 25,
     3 => 25,
     4 => 25,
     5 => 25,
     6 => 25,
);

for ($i=1, $c = count($array); $i<$c; ++$i) {
    $array[$i] += $array[$i-1];

}

var_dump($array);
```

I have no idea why all other answers use foreach loop in this case as for in my opinion is better to do that (no conditions, no temporary variables, no unset references from foreach).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
<?php
$yourarray = array(460, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25);
$l = 0;
foreach($yourarray as $b){
$l = $b+$l;
echo $last;
}
```

Outputs `460485510535560585610`

Comment: This is just a copy of @wumm 's [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24950227/2518525)....

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
$array  = array( 460, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25);
$result = array();

for ($i=count($array);$i>0; $i--){
    $result[($i-1)]  = array_sum($array);
    array_pop($array);
}

echo "<pre>";
ksort($result);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 460
    [1] => 485
    [2] => 510
    [3] => 535
    [4] => 560
    [5] => 585
    [6] => 610
)
```